# Importing Excel With JXLS: is it possible to specify sheet by order rather than name?

Tags: java, excel, import, jxls

I'm using the JXLS XLSReader to read in Microsoft Excel files.

This is a copy of my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<workbook>
  <worksheet name="staff_acme">
    <loop startRow="1" endRow="1" items="VECIDataHolder" var="vdh" varType="gov.noaa.nsd.model.data.dataholders.VECIDataHolder">
      <section startRow="1" endRow="1">
        <mapping row="1" col="0">vdh.person_id</mapping>
        <mapping row="1" col="1">vdh.fullname</mapping>
        <mapping row="1" col="2">vdh.noaa_email_address</mapping>
        <mapping row="1" col="3">vdh.emergency_email_address</mapping>
        <mapping row="1" col="4">vdh.emergency_cell</mapping>
        <mapping row="1" col="5">vdh.emergency_sms</mapping>
      </section>
      <loopbreakcondition>
        <rowcheck offset="0">
          <cellcheck offset="0"/>
        </rowcheck>
      </loopbreakcondition>
    </loop>
  </worksheet>
</workbook>
```

My users have been changing the name of the sheet, which makes JXLS miss it.

Is there a way to tell JXLS to just read the first sheet and only the first sheet no matter what its name is?   I couldn't find anything on Google, but if you can please feel free to post a link

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

From jxls page:

> As of version 1.0.2 jxls-reader supports mapping of sheets by index. This can be convenient in case you do not know the names of the sheets.

Just use

```
<worksheet idx="0">
```

instead of

```
<worksheet name="sheetName">
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer.  He said this feature does not exist, yet.  He will think about putting it in a future release.

As a workaround, he suggested reading in the workbook using POI API to find out the sheet name. Then updating the XML config in memory with a proper sheet name and supply it to ReaderBuilder or build the config without XML but with API calls.

HTH someone else Googling on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by coberty you can use

```
<worksheet idx="0">
```

But for the sake of completeness: I had a similar problem, but I needed to specify a sheet name at runtime (user selects from a list of sheets of a user selected Excel file, reading the sheet names via Apache POI). I accomplished this by using the JXLS Reader example from the website and changing it a bit:

Instead of:

```
  final XLSReader reader = ReaderBuilder.buildFromXML(xmlInputStream);
```

I use a copy of this method with a little change using Apache Digester setSubstitutor (unfortunately the ReaderBuilder does not allow passing a substitutor as parameter...):

```
  final XLSReader reader = buildFromXML(xmlInputStream, sheetName);

  ...


  public static XLSReader buildFromXML(final InputStream xmlStream, final String sheetName)
         throws IOException, SAXException {

      final Digester digester = new Digester();

      // hier geschieht die Substituierung des Tabellenblattnamens -
      // der Rest der Methode entspricht dem Original
      substituteSheetName(sheetName, digester);

      digester.setValidating(false);
      digester.addObjectCreate("workbook", "org.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl");
      digester.addObjectCreate("workbook/worksheet", "org.jxls.reader.XLSSheetReaderImpl");
      digester.addSetProperties("workbook/worksheet", "name", "sheetName");
      digester.addSetProperties("workbook/worksheet", "idx", "sheetIdx");
      digester.addSetNext("workbook/worksheet", "addSheetReader");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/loop", "org.jxls.reader.XLSForEachBlockReaderImpl");
      digester.addSetProperties("*/loop");
      digester.addSetNext("*/loop", "addBlockReader");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/section", "org.jxls.reader.SimpleBlockReaderImpl");
      digester.addSetProperties("*/section");
      digester.addSetNext("*/section", "addBlockReader");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/mapping", "org.jxls.reader.BeanCellMapping");
      digester.addSetProperties("*/mapping");
      digester.addCallMethod("*/mapping", "setFullPropertyName", 1);
      digester.addCallParam("*/mapping", 0);
      digester.addSetNext("*/mapping", "addMapping");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/loop/loopbreakcondition", "org.jxls.reader.SimpleSectionCheck");
      digester.addSetNext("*/loop/loopbreakcondition", "setLoopBreakCondition");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/loopbreakcondition/rowcheck", "org.jxls.reader.OffsetRowCheckImpl");
      digester.addSetProperties("*/loopbreakcondition/rowcheck");
      digester.addSetNext("*/loopbreakcondition/rowcheck", "addRowCheck");
      digester.addObjectCreate("*/rowcheck/cellcheck", "org.jxls.reader.OffsetCellCheckImpl");
      digester.addSetProperties("*/rowcheck/cellcheck");
      digester.addCallMethod("*/rowcheck/cellcheck", "setValue", 1);
      digester.addCallParam("*/rowcheck/cellcheck", 0);
      digester.addSetNext("*/rowcheck/cellcheck", "addCellCheck");
      return (XLSReader) digester.parse(xmlStream);
   }

   private static void substituteSheetName(final String sheetName, final Digester digester) {
      // set up the variables the input xml can reference
      final Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      vars.put("sheetName", sheetName);

      // map ${varname} to the entries in the var map
      final MultiVariableExpander expander = new MultiVariableExpander();
      expander.addSource("$", vars);

      // allow expansion in both xml attributes and element text
      final Substitutor substitutor = new VariableSubstitutor(expander);

      digester.setSubstitutor(substitutor);
   }
```

Now I can use the variable sheetName in the JXLS Reader XML configuration:

```
   <worksheet name="${sheetName}">
```